# Mixed canonical transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) and most authors denote four types of canonical transformations: $F_1(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{Q})$
, $F_2(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{P})$, $F_3(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{Q})$ and $F_4(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{P})$. However, is it possible (or necessary, perhaps) to define a transformation that mixes both "old" and "new" canonical variables?

For instance, the following transformation is canonical:
$$
\begin{matrix}
Q_1=q_1, & P_1=p_1-2p_2,\\
Q_2=p_2, & P_2=-2q_1-q_2.
\end{matrix}
$$

I have found that a possible generating function for this transformation would be 
$$
G(q_1,q_2,P_1,Q_2)=P_1q_1+Q_2(2q_1+q_2),
$$
which doesn't fit any of the four traditional types.

P.S.: I found $G$ by (i) making a canonical tranformation $\tilde{Q}_2=-P_2$, $\tilde{P}_2=Q_2$, (ii) finding a $F_2$-type function and (iii) reverting back to $Q_2,P_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Classical Mechanics (Third Edition), H. Goldstein, Chapter 9, Page 374*:

> [...]
>
> Finally, note that a suitable generating function doesn't have to conform to one of the four basic types for *all* degrees of freedom of the system. It is possible. for some canonical transformations necessary, to use a generating function that is a mixture of the four types. To take a simple example, it may be desirable for a particular canonical transformation with two degrees of freedom to be defined by a generating function of the form $$F'(q_1,p_2,P_1,Q_2,t)$$[...]

I think that essentially answers your question.

Comment: @RenanNobuyukiHirayama I have practically adopted the view that if it is classical mechanics, it is in Goldstein!